# Search SQL statement

Tags: sql

I have a table name `chat_customer` which has customer attribute:

```
id, name, status, ...
```

I also have a table name `chat_friendRelationship` and `myId` and my `friendId` can be either in column1 or column2. How to search all my `friendId`?

My query is

```
SELECT 
    CHAT_CUSTOMER.CUSTOMERID, CHAT_CUSTOMER.CUSTOMERNAME,
    CHAT_CUSTOMER.STATUS, CHAT_CUSTOMER.LASTLOGIN, CHAT_CUSTOMER.ISADMIN
FROM 
    CHAT_CUSTOMER 
LEFT JOIN 
    CHAT_FRIENDRELATIONSHIP ON CHAT_CUSTOMER.CUSTOMERID = CHAT_FRIENDRELATIONSHIP.CUSTOMERID1
                            OR CHAT_CUSTOMER.CUSTOMERID = CHAT_FRIENDRELATIONSHIP.CUSTOMERID2
WHERE 
    CHAT_CUSTOMER.CUSTOMERID = '1';
```

But it returns some rows with my data. I want it to return my friend data.

Those images below are my tables.

chat_customer Table:

[image: chat_customer Table]

chat_relationship Table:

[image: chat_relationship Table]

Comment: Do two joins on that same table. One time using customerID1  the second time using customerID2

Answer (score 2):

For full details of frinds:

```
select
      c.*
from chat_customer c
inner join (
      select distinct customerid2
      from chat_relationship
      where customerid1 = '1'
      ) friends on c.customerid = friends.customerid2
```

nb: It's not clear from the example if DISTINCT is required or not

For just a list of friends by an id:

```
      select distinct customerid2
      from chat_relationship
      where customerid1 = '1'
```

Comment: what is "friends" here in "friends on c.customerid = friends.customerid2" ?

Comment: friends is the alias he gave that subquery. So anything in the select of that subquery can be used friends.blah

Comment: @FirebladeDan well can't be certain, but I think so. person wants only the friends listed, so if searching for customer 1, customer 1 should not be in the results, just the friends.

Comment: You ask: what is "friends"?  It IS and `alias` as Dan said, it gives a names to that subquery so I can refer to it by that name. Note because you don't specify which dbms you use I left out the "AS" keyword because Oracle doesn't like it for subqueries.

Comment: @Used_By_Already - you need the single ticks aaround '1' and should be good to go. #pro

Comment: thanks, done. (when I see ID I assume its an integer)

Comment: Thanks both of you. I think it's complicated and not nessessary. I think I just want to display friendId, the rest (name, status, ...) is not displayed.

Comment: `I think I just want to display friendId` then do just that, you didn't specify which columns you needed. I will amend the answer however.

Answer (score 2):

Another way to write your query, longer for sure, but maybe a little more understandable for some of us and it will display all the data of the friends of costumer_id = 1:

```
    SELECT   
      CHAT_CUSTOMER.CUSTOMERID  
      CHAT_CUSTOMER.CUSTOMERNAME,  
      CHAT_CUSTOMER.STATUS,  
      CHAT_CUSTOMER.LASTLOGIN,  
      CHAT_CUSTOMER.ISADMIN  
    FROM   
      CHAT_CUSTOMER   
        JOIN CHAT_FRIENDRELATIONSHIP ON 
           CHAT_CUSTOMER.CUSTOMERID = CHAT_FRIENDRELATIONSHIP.CUSTOMERID1
    WHERE
      CHAT_FRIENDRELATIONSHIP.CUSTOMERID2 = 1
    UNION
    SELECT  
      CHAT_CUSTOMER.CUSTOMERID  
      CHAT_CUSTOMER.CUSTOMERNAME,  
      CHAT_CUSTOMER.STATUS,  
      CHAT_CUSTOMER.LASTLOGIN,  
      CHAT_CUSTOMER.ISADMIN  
    FROM
      CHAT_CUSTOMER   
        JOIN CHAT_FRIENDRELATIONSHIP ON 
          CHAT_CUSTOMER.CUSTOMERID = CHAT_FRIENDRELATIONSHIP.CUSTOMERID2
    WHERE 
      CHAT_FRIENDRELATIONSHIP.CUSTOMERID1 = 1
  ;
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example of getting both searches:

```
select 
c.customerid, 
c.customername, 
c.status,
cr.columnname1,
cr.columnname2,
cr2.columnname1,
cr2.columnname2
from 
chat_customer c
join chat_relationship cr
on c.customerid = cr.customerid1
join chat_relationship cr2
on c.customerid = cr2.customerid2
where c.customer_id = '1';
```

Comment: It still displays my data, not friend data. Instead of displaying some rows with same data, it display only one.

Comment: My where clause is on chat_customer. It'll show both matching items from chat_relationship. can you show an example of what you want to see?

Comment: If my searchId is 1, then the table displays same columns as table Chat_customer but data only for id 2, 3, 11111 because only 2, 3, 11111 are 1's friends.

Comment: Thank you. I think I just want to display friend Id only.